# how to use a same parameter as a drop down and text box based on previous parameters in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report which has 3 parameters.
Two date parameters which can accept NULL. The third parameter should always be entered for the report to display.
I want the third parameter to act as a 'Textbox' so a user can enter values when the first 2 parameters are NULL. When the first 2 parameters are not NULL, the third parameter becomes a Dropdown selection.

I have created a dataset for the third parameter to feed on based on the 2 parameters -

```
 IF @StartDate is NULL and @EndDate is NULL
 select NULL as ID
 IF @StartDate is not null and @EndDate is not NULL
 select ID from table when date between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

When I run the report with date parameters NULL, third parameter displays a blank textbox, but when I enter a value - it just displays blank report.
It looks like the report query is not overwriting the NULL value selected.

[When I enter any value in the Batch ID parameter and click on "View report", it just returns blank page with 3rd parameter blank. NO report is being displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpsVA.jpg)

Any ideas to approach this scenario are appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Could you post some screeshot as well? The problem is not very clear to me.

Comment: @WilliamXu - I tried adding a screenshot of how the report looks like. But not sure if it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the third parameter be both an open textbox AND a single select drop-down list. You'll need a fourth parameter for this.

The dataset you shared will work for the drop-down, but you will need to have a default value other than NULL. In the parameter properties, set the Available Values to pull from this dataset.

Add a fourth parameter that is a textbox. Allow blank values.

In your main dataset you will need to handle these parameters either in the query or as dataset filters. For example, the end of your query could look like this:

```
WHERE BatchID in @BatchIdList or BatchID = @BatchIdTextbox
```

Comment: Thank you Steven. It did work with the fourth parameter.